# How to change nginx port on debian8.3 + plesk 12.5 and set varnish listen on port 80?

Tags: nginx, debian, varnish, plesk

Changing the default http port on nginx with Plesk 12.5 is my biggest problem I know how to set up Varnish.
I also know to do this on the server with out the Plesk.
My OS is Debian 8.3,  I wind some instructions for Centos but they were unhelpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways

1. Official with trade-offs:

   customizing Plesk's web server configs templates as described here https://talk.plesk.com/threads/solved-help-required-change-nginx-port.331439/

   You have to starts with creating folder `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom` and copying following files from `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default`:

   ```
   nginx.php
   nginxDomainForwarding.php
   nginxDomainForwardingIpDefault.php
   nginxDomainVhost.php
   nginxDomainVhostIpDefault.php
   nginxWebmail.php
   ```

   and replace `$VAR->server->nginx->httpPort` in each file with port number you want.

   **Trade-offs are:** after upgrade to next version you should perform this procedure again. All changes which will be performed by updates for `default` templates will be not applies to you.
2. Fast with unknown side effects: just change ports in table ServiceNodeConfiguration:

   mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "select * from ServiceNodeConfiguration where section = 'webProxy'"

   ```
   +---------------+----------+-----------------+-------+
   | serviceNodeId | section  | name            | value |
   +---------------+----------+-----------------+-------+
   |             1 | webProxy | enabled         | true  |
   |             1 | webProxy | frontendPort    | 80    |
   |             1 | webProxy | sslFrontendPort | 443   |
   +---------------+----------+-----------------+-------+
   ```

And don't forget for `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all`

Comment: `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all` needs to be run also for option 1 (I did not do it because it was indented as if only necessary for option 2).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good command to change port 80 in database for nginx. Varnish now can work through port 80.

```sql
mysql -uadmin -p$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow) -Dpsa -e "update ServiceNodeConfiguration set value=8080 where section = 'webProxy' and name ='frontendPort'";
```